# Python Script, Pandas Special Characters

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this script to geocode addresses. The script works fine, however the output file converts special characters such as `中央区` and `Athénée` to gibberish. i.e.

`中央区` -> `ä¸­å¤®åŒº`

`Athénée` -> `AthÃ©nÃ©e`

The input file is a UTF-8 .CSV saved in MAC excel. The script is using Pandas to process data. How could I support special characters such as the above?

The code for the full script can be found here: 
https://github.com/shanealynn/python_batch_geocode/blob/master/python_batch_geocoding.py

```
 import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import logging
    import time

    #------------------ CONFIGURATION -------------------------------

    # Set your output file name here.
    output_filename = '/Users/_Library/Python/geobatch/res1000_output.csv'
    # Set your input file here
    input_filename = "/Users/_Library/Python/geobatch/res1000.csv"
    # Specify the column name in your input data that contains addresses here
    address_column_name = "Address"
    # Return Full Google Results? If True, full JSON results from Google are included in output
    RETURN_FULL_RESULTS = False

    #------------------ DATA LOADING --------------------------------

    # Read the data to a Pandas Dataframe
    data = pd.read_csv(input_filename, encoding='utf8')

    addresses = data[address_column_name].tolist()


    # All done
    logger.info("Finished geocoding all addresses")
    # Write the full results to csv using the pandas library.
    pd.DataFrame(results).to_csv(output_filename, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: "gibberish" isn't particularly helpful for us to understand how to fix the problem

Comment: sorry please see updated question

Comment: Have you tried viewing the file in the variable explorer before outputting it?

Comment: how could I do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is the solution I am working with:

```
# Write the full results to csv using the pandas library.
pd.DataFrame(results).to_csv(output_filename, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I insert the line:

```
data['Address'] = data['Address'].map(lambda x: x.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8'))
```

to decode and re-encode the inputs - then output becomes.

`中央区` -> `\u4e2d\u592e\u533a` instead of `ä¸­å¤®åŒº`

which is one step closer to the right direction I presume, if someone could built on this?